# How to mock non virtual methods?

Tags: c#, .net, moq

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<EmailService>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.SendEmail()).Returns(true);
    var cus = new Customer();
    var result = cus.AddCustomer(mock.Object);
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}

public class Customer
{
    public bool AddCustomer(EmailService emailService)
    {
        emailService.SendEmail();
        Debug.WriteLine("new customer added");
        return true;
    }
}

public class EmailService
{            
    public virtual bool SendEmail()
    {
        throw  new Exception("send email failed cuz bla bla bla");
    }
}
```

The `EmailService.SendEmail` method must be virtual to mock it. Is there any way to mock non virtual methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking non-virtual methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073684/mocking-non-virtual-methods-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Moq cannot mock non virtual methods on classes. Either use other mocking frameworks such as [Type mock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page/) which actually weaves IL into your assembly or place an interface on `EmailService` and mock that.

Comment: I know this a very old post, but had some similar issue. Are there any down sides of converting the method into virtual, when the actual application runs?

Comment: I recommend asking a separate question in SO.

Answer (score 9):

Mocking non virtual methods involves the use of low level profiler API. At the moment I think the only options available are :

- [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/)
- [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx/)

both are commercial, even if JustMock have a lite edition, mocking non virtual methods are available just with the commercial version.
As pointed in the comments there is something from Microsoft research, in the project [Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)

Comment: I think you can add Microsoft Moles/Pex/Fakes to that list. As a bonus, it's free.

Comment: Microsoft Fakes is "free" if you have an enterprise edition of visual studio.

Answer (score 8):

Updated july 2020:
`pose` Has been abandoned, current recommendation is:
https://github.com/riezebosch/Unmockable
Thanks to @Customizer for pointing out.

I was also checking out https://github.com/Serg046/AutoFake which seems viable from @Serg046
——
Use `pose`. Allows you to replace any method including static or non virtual. Fairly new project, but fully open source MIT license.
https://github.com/tonerdo/pose

Comment: Seems to be dead: https://github.com/tonerdo/pose/issues/51. The framework
https://github.com/riezebosch/Unmockable is advertised as an alternative in this issue.

Answer (score 6):

The alternative to having to use virtual methods for mocking is to use interfaces. This way you can mock out a whole dependency.

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    bool SendEmail();
    // etc...
}

public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    //...
}
```

Now you can create mocks of the interface `IEmailService` to let you mock any of its methods. Of course, you'll have to change the types of variables containing `EmailService` objects to `IEmailService` where appropriate.

Comment: I think using this technique is good, and there are certainly advantages to using interfaces.   But if you're evaluating between the two options for a non-virtual method to be mockable: 1) make it virtual, 2) use it as part of the interface, what is the advantage of 2 over 1?   Even if you pick 2, then you're effectively making the method virtual since it's now part of an interface.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this question much time ago and realized that I would want to create something opensourced to solve the issue. So it is ready - [AutoFake](https://github.com/Serg046/AutoFake). The most exciting thing is that it doesn't require any crazy CLR Profiler API. It is just a normal .NET package and that's it. Bellow is the example of what you can do using the library:

```
public class Calendar
{
    public static DateTime Yesterday => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    internal Task<DateTime> AddSomeMinutesAsync(DateTime date) => Task.Run(() => AddSomeMinutes(date));
    public static DateTime AddSomeMinutes(DateTime date) => date.AddMinutes(new Random().Next(1, 10));
}

[Fact]
public void Yesterday_SomeDay_ThePrevDay()
{
    var fake = new Fake<Calendar>();

    var sut = fake.Rewrite(() => Calendar.Yesterday);
    sut.Replace(() => DateTime.Now).Return(new DateTime(2016, 8, day: 8));

    Assert.Equal(new DateTime(2016, 8, 7), sut.Execute());
}

[Fact]
public async Task AddSomeMinutesAsync_SomeDay_MinutesAdded()
{
    var randomValue = 7;
    var date = new DateTime(2016, 8, 8, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0);
    var fake = new Fake<Calendar>();

    var sut = fake.Rewrite(f => f.AddSomeMinutesAsync(date));
    sut.Replace((Random r) => r.Next(1, 10)) // Arg.Is<int>(i => i == 10) is also possible
                           // r.Next(1, 11) fails with "Expected - 11, actual - 10"
        .ExpectedCalls(1) // c => c > 1 fails with "Actual value - 1"
        .Return(randomValue);

    Assert.Equal(date.AddMinutes(randomValue), await sut.Execute());
}

[Fact]
public void AddSomeMinutes_SomeDay_EventsRecorded()
{
    var events = new List<string>();
    var fake = new Fake<Calendar>();

    var sut = fake.Rewrite(() => Calendar.AddSomeMinutes(new DateTime(2016, 8, 8)));

    sut.Prepend(() => events.Add("The first line"));
    sut.Prepend(() => events.Add("The line before AddMinutes(...) call"))
        .Before((DateTime date) => date.AddMinutes(Arg.IsAny<int>()));

    sut.Append(() => events.Add("The line after new Random() call"))
        .After(() => new Random());
    sut.Append(() => events.Add("The last line"));

    sut.Execute();
    Assert.Equal(new[]
        {
            "The first line",
            "The line after new Random() call", // indeed, this call is earlier
            "The line before AddMinutes(...) call",
            "The last line"
        },
        events);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @aqwert and @Felice wrote when using [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/) it's possible (and pretty easy) to mock Non-virtual methods without adding or changing any code, for example:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mock = Isolate.Fake.Instance<EmailService>();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => mock.SendEmail()).WillReturn(true);
        var cust = new Customer();
        var result = cust.AddCustomer(mock);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
```

as you can see the test i've created is similar to the test you tried to create.

Comment: It is commercial package

Answer (score 0):

The only way to mock non virtual methods is to mock interface used to implement that class with non virtual methods. Below is the example.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    DateTime GetDateofJoining(int id);
}

public class Employee
{
    public DateTime GetDateofJoining(int id)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}

    public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employee = new Mock<IEmployee>();
        employee.Setup(x => x.GetDateofJoining(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int x) => DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine(employee.Object.GetDateofJoining(1));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you can use not the method itself but create virtual wrapper method instead

```
public class EmailService
{     
    protected virtual void SendEmailReal(){
        throw  new Exception("send email failed cuz bla bla bla");
    }
        
    public void bool SendEmail()
    {
        return SendEmailReal();
    }
}
```

And then override it in the test class:

```
abstract class TestEmailService: EmailService{

     public abstract override  bool SendEmailReal();
}
```

The test methods itself:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<TestEmailService>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.SendEmailReal()).Returns(true);
    var cus = new Customer();
    var result = cus.AddCustomer(mock.Object);
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: this answer did have 2 upwotes but now it has -1, similar things I see with other answers(not mine) over staskowerflow, staskowerflow is accupied by some upset bots?