# Mocking a Single Bucket object in ElasticSearch using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq to mock a SingleBucket object in ElasticSearch. Basically I need to have it return 5 documents (property `.DocCount`)

```
var sb = new Mock<SingleBucket>();
sb.SetupGet(x => x.DocCount).Returns(5);
```

I tried that and I get an exception:

```
{System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual
(overridable in VB) member: x => x.DocCount
```

What's wrong with this code?
Seems to be ok to mock a property using `SetupGet`

I know I should mock either the interface or a virtual method. Is there any chance to mock that object property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specified already, `Moq` cannot mock non-virtual method. You can either wrap `SingleBucket` into an interface, either use [another mocking framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738228/4172979).