# Incorrect setup in MOQ in the Lambda calling a property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq

MOQ questions often get people pointing back to the documents , which is cool and all but I think I need some help understanding what this error comes from  ( maybe my knowledge of lambda expressions is off )

I have a MOQ test

```
var mockTicket = new Mock<Ticket>();
        mockTicket.Setup(tix => tix.Total).Returns(var expectedResult = 5); 
        cashRegister.PendingTickets.Add(mockTicket.Object);


        //act 
        var actual = cashRegister.CloseTicket(mockTicket.Object);
        // FYI . close ticket returns the total of the tickets hence this is logical to the point that the 
        // ticket is the price being returned. 

        //assert
        Assert.Equals(actual, expectedResult);
```

and my errors are

```
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: tix => tix.Total
```

and also Total is just a get

```
       public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Decimal.Round(ItemsOrdered.Sum(x => x.Price + x.Tax), 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you need to mock the interface, not the class in that case... as in, I think you need an ITicket interface that Ticket implements.

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know.  `Total` is non-virtual, so it's invalid to set it up.  [Moq cannot mock non-virtual members](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738166/1698557).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the mocking you would need to have an `ITicket` interface to pass into your method, then your `cashRegister` doesn't need a concrete `Ticket` and you can use a known good value for `Total`.

Additionally, you don't need the `var` set in the return. You would be able to use:

```
var mockTicket = new Mock<ITicket>();
mockTicket.Setup(tix => tix.Total).Returns(5);
```

Additionally, you would need to change `cashRegister.PendingTotal` and `cashRegister.CloseTicket` to have `ITicket` in the signature instead of `Ticket`.

Alternatively, you can arrange a concrete `Ticket` class to return a known good value for `Total`.

---

Additionally, I wouldn't alter the `Ticket` class to have a `virtual` `Total` property on it, just to facilitate this testing, you would be allowing the tests to pollute the code needlessly.

Comment: as soon as @jkerak said it my eyes opened up.