# How to mock/ override readonly fields for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, readonly, microsoft-fakes, nsubstitute

I am using nj4x and it has a class that has readonly fields as follows.

```
   public class MarketInformation
    {
    public readonly double ASK;
    public readonly double BID;
    public readonly double DIGITS;
    public readonly double EXPIRATION;
    public readonly double FREEZELEVEL;
    }
```

I am writing unit tests for classes and methods writing these classes. For isolation/ mocking I am using Nsubstitute and MicrosoftFakes (shims mainly). I want to override these fields so when they are called in my methods I get predictable results for testing.
I generated shim for this class but all it provides me is a constructor, now allowing me to initialize it still. Is there any way to set these fields from outside this class?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable with mocks/fakes etc. but isn't the idea that you set your hard-coded predictable values for your fields *inside* the mock class, i.e. you don't need to pass it in or assign it from outside.  A mock is supposed to *be* an implementation of the abstraction that you're mocking, just like the "real" class is in an implementation.

Comment: @rory.ap implementing mocks is a seperate idea however, I am using frameworks for mocking and isolation. Implementing mocks require abstract/interface classes. however those are not available here.

Comment: You need to create an interface which you can mock. The members need to be `virtual`. (NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the class, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute!) [reference](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/)

Comment: I am using nj4x library. Cannot create interfaces.

Comment: Then I would recommend to switch to a mocking library which supports non virutal members ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738228/6583901)). Why do you eaven need to mock fields? This shouldn't be a use case..

Comment: public double GetAskPrice(SymbolType sym)
        {
            // other code
            return _conn.Gc.Marketinfo(sym.DisplayName).ASK;
        }
Like in this method Marketinfo(sym.DisplayName) is an instance of this class. I need that double value ask, to make this method independant of MarketInformation class. MarketInformation gets values from server, always changing. I need more predictable results for testing.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't pretty, but if you have access to the instance that needs to be modified, you can use [the `SetField` method of the `PrivateObject` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243988.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The `PrivateObject` class is part of the MS unit testing framework.

For example, consider the class:

```
public class ClassWithReadOnly
{
    public readonly string Foo;

    public ClassWithReadOnly()
    {
        Foo = "bar";
    }
}
```

You can set the read-only field like so:

```
var test = new ClassWithReadOnly();
Console.WriteLine("Before Foo == '{0}'", test.Foo);
var po = new PrivateObject(test);
po.SetField("Foo", "oof");
Console.WriteLine("After Foo == '{0}'", test.Foo);
```

The output will be:

> Before Foo == 'bar'
>
> After Foo == 'oof'

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to create a wrapper class with your own `get` properties to stub or shim it out.  You could create your own interface if you wanted to use stubs (not shown).

```
public class MarketInformationWrapper : MarketInformation
{
    ...
    public double Ask
    {
        get { return ASK; }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I doubt it won't do me any good. This will work only when I can pass the object into class or method under test. 
What I want is something what shims do.
Like I create a shim for class dummy, say shimDummy. then I can just say
 shimDummy.AllInstances.Ask = (Dummy) => 5;
this way i will get 5 whenever it is invoked.