# Mocking non virtual posted model properties and method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have person model class defined as:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public bool SelectionSubmitted = false;

    public bool ShowValidationSummary = false;

    public string Name;

    public string Get()
    {            
        //actual implementation return some value from the db
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The controller implementation is as follows:

```
class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(PersonModel model)
    {
        if (model.SelectionSubmitted && !ValidateSelections(model))
        {
            model.ShowValidationSummary = true;
        }

        return View("Index", model.Get());
    }

    private bool ValidateSelections(PersonModel model)
    {
        if(model.Name == "")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmptyPersonName", "Person name cannot be null");
        }
        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }       
}
```

The test class and method is defined as:

```
[TestClass]
public class ChildWithoutPlacementControllerTest
{
    private readonly Mock<PersonModel> _mockPersonModel;

    public ChildWithoutPlacementControllerTest()
    {
        _mockPersonModel = new Mock<PersonModel>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenPerson_WhenSearchingForFutureBirthDate_ThenValidationMessageShouldBeShown()
    {
        //Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        _mockPersonModel.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
        _mockPersonModel.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns(string.Empty);
        _mockPersonModel.SetupGet(x => x.SelectionSubmitted).Returns(true);

        //Act
        controller.Index(_mockPersonModel.Object);

        //Assert
        var isShowSummarySetToTrue = _mockPersonModel.Object.ShowValidationSummary;
        Assert.IsTrue(isShowSummarySetToTrue);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is mock the `SelectionSubmitted` and `Name` property to `true` and `string.Empty` respectively also `Setup` the `Get` method of `PersonModel` class, and check if the test return object has `ShowValidationSummary` set to `true`.

However, I am getting that I can't set up the non-virtual property Name.

Am I doing something wrong or is there any way to do it without changing the implementation code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock non virtual methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738102/how-to-mock-non-virtual-methods)

Comment: @nkosi I guess you posted an answer however can't find it now. It really helped that approach worked well for me. Thank you so much!!.

Comment: I found an issue with it and was reviewing the problem. You should really consider refactoring your code to make it more testable.

Comment: Yes, I am looking into that how I can make it more testable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> is there any way to do it without changing the implementation code

There really is no need for moq in this scenario. You can use inheritance to craft a fake model to be used in the test. The fake model will override the method that is tightly coupled to the database. (more on that later)

```
public class FakePerson : PersonModel {
    public new string Get() {
        return string.Empty; //Not calling the base Get
    }
}
```

The test can then be refactored to use the fake model and be exercised to completion as intended.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GivenPerson_WhenSearchingForFutureBirthDate_ThenValidationMessageShouldBeShown() {
    //Arrange
    var fakePersonModel = new FakePerson() {
        Name = string.Empty,
        SelectionSubmitted = true
    };
    var controller = new HomeController();

    //Act
    controller.Index(fakePersonModel);

    //Assert
    var isShowSummarySetToTrue = fakePersonModel.ShowValidationSummary;
    Assert.IsTrue(isShowSummarySetToTrue);
}
```

That aside, your model appears to be doing to much if the actual `Get` implementation does as you stated here

> actual implementation return some value from the db

Consider refactoring that functionality out into a service (Single Responsibility Principle / Separation of Concerns)

```
public interface IPersonModelService {
    string Get(PersonModel person);
}

public class PersonModelService : IPersonModelService {

    public string Get(PersonModel person) {
        //actual implementation return some value from the db
    }
}
```

and keep the model as lean as possible. Also consider refactoring those public fields into public properties.

```
public class PersonModel {
    public bool SelectionSubmitted { get; set; }

    public bool ShowValidationSummary { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

The controller would depend on the service abstraction

```
class HomeController : Controller {
    private IPersonModelService service;

    public HomeController(IPersonModelService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(PersonModel model) {
        if (model.SelectionSubmitted && !ValidateSelections(model)) {
            model.ShowValidationSummary = true;
        }

        return View("Index", service.Get(model));
    }

    private bool ValidateSelections(PersonModel model) {
        if (model.Name == "") {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmptyPersonName", "Person name cannot be null");
        }
        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```

And now the test can be exercised to completion in isolation.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GivenPerson_WhenSearchingForFutureBirthDate_ThenValidationMessageShouldBeShown() {
    //Arrange
    var model = new PersonModel() {
        Name = string.Empty,
        SelectionSubmitted = true
    };

    var serviceMock = new Mock<IPersonModelService>();
    serviceMock.Setup(_ => _.Get(It.IsAny<PersonModel>())).Returns(string.Empty);
    var controller = new HomeController(serviceMock.Object);

    //Act
    controller.Index(model);

    //Assert
    var isShowSummarySetToTrue = model.ShowValidationSummary;
    Assert.IsTrue(isShowSummarySetToTrue);
}
```