# Mocking action c#

Tags: c#, delegates, moq

I'm trying to mock an action that console writes "hi" when it gets invoked but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression'.

Here is what I got and maybe I am not doing this correctly:

```html
var actionMock = Mock.Of<Action>();
var getActionMock = Mock.Get(actionMock);

getActionMock.Setup(c => c.Invoke()).Callback(() => {
    Console.Write("hi");
});
```

Any help or suggestion would be great!

Comment: Not sure if related, but Invoke is not virtual, so not sure if you can mock it like that. Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738102/how-to-mock-non-virtual-methods

Comment: Why would you possibly ever need to mock Action? If you need to send/inject an Action to something you are testing, just create one like normal. You wouldn’t try to mock an int or string.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense @AndrewP

Comment: I initially wanted to mock the action so I can verify that if it got invoked @DaveM

Comment: You don’t need to mock an action to achieve that. Just make one.

Comment: Sounds good and thanks @Dav